# Looking for read Text file into batch file when both files are in different directories

Tags: batch-file, create-directory

I have one batch file in `C:\Projects\FileServer\Scripts\A.bat` folder and Text File in `C:\Projects\FileServer\B.txt`. I want to read `B.txt` first line into one variable in my batch file which will get executed from `C:\Projects\FileServer\Scripts` location.

I tried below but didnt work - not able to find txt file

```
set /p fileserver=< B.txt
echo %fileserver%

set folder=%fileserver%\TestData
if not exist "%folder%" mkdir %folder%
```

Comment: You need to take care of potential issues by getting in the habit of using doublequotes. **`Set/P "fileserver="<"..\B.txt"`**, **`Set "folder=%fileserver%\TestData"`** and **`If Not Exist "%folder%\" MD "%folder%"`**

Comment: `< "%~dp0..\B.txt" set /P fileserver=""` should work (`%~dp0` points to the directory containing the script with a trailing `\ `; `..` goes one directory level up)...

Comment: It worked fine if we have to go one level up. Didn't worked if giving complete path in othermachine or in other drive. Some thing like -      
 Set/P "fileserver="<"D:\MyData\B.txt" or Set/P "fileserver="<"\\192.10.10.1\MyData\B.txt" ???

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a wrong path.
Try this:

```
set /p fileserver=< ..\B.txt
```

Comment: The current working directory is not necessarily the directory containing the batch script...

Comment: It worked fine if we have to go one level up. Didn't worked if giving complete path in othermachine or in other drive. Some thing like -      
 Set/P "fileserver="<"D:\MyData\B.txt" or Set/P "fileserver="<"\\192.10.10.1\MyData\B.txt" ???

Comment: Are you using all those double quotes? 
`Set/P "fileserver="<"D:\MyData\B.txt"`
Try removing all the double quotes like this:
`set /p fileserve =< D:\MyData\B.txt`.